# i,m updating my tasks from true to false with set() method but instead adds a new item

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I want the status to be updated from false to true on click of a button

```js
 $scope.complete = function(key) {
 $scope.status = taskref.child("users").child(authData.uid).child('task').child(key).set({status: 'true'});
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To *update* a subset of the properties of an item, use the `update()` method:

```
taskref.child("users")
       .child(authData.uid)
       .child('task')
       .child(key)
       .update({status: true});
```

This will update only the `status` property and leave the others unmodified.